# Max MInd Omni Web Service Array into Variables

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I am using the Max Mind Omni web service and am using their PHP example code.

I am new to using curl and i am trying to find out the best way to seperate the array in to individual variables which i can insert into a database table.

below is an example of the code i am using.  When I run this code I can not seem to get the individual value of the omni keys.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
 if (!isset($params['i'])) $params['i'] = '82.150.248.29';

 $query = 'https://geoip.maxmind.com/e?' . http_build_query($params);

 $omni_keys = 
   array(
    'country_code',
    'country_name',
    'region_code',
    'region_name',
    'city_name',
    'latitude',
    'longitude',
    'metro_code',
    'area_code',
    'time_zone',
    'continent_code',
    'postal_code',
    'isp_name',
    'organization_name',
    'domain',
    'as_number',
    'netspeed',
    'user_type',
    'accuracy_radius',
    'country_confidence',
    'city_confidence',
    'region_confidence',
    'postal_confidence',
    'error'
    );

   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array( $curl, 
               array(
                     CURLOPT_URL => $query,
                     CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'MaxMind PHP Sample',
                     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
                     )
               );

            $resp = curl_exec($curl);

          if (curl_errno($curl)) {
            throw new Exception('GeoIP Request Failed');
              }

                  $omni_values = str_getcsv($resp);
                $omni = array_combine( $omni_keys, $omni_values);

                //print_r($omni_values);

                 $country_code=$omni_value[0];
                 $country_name=$omni_value[1];
                 echo "$country_code";
                 echo "$country_name";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your code....

```
$country_code= $omni_values[0]; //instead of $omni_value[0];
```

This line in it makes it into an associative array.

```
$omni = array_combine( $omni_keys, $omni_values);
```

So you'll make a few changes like so:

```
$country_code= $omni['country_code']; //instead of $omni_value[0];
$country_name= $omni['country_name']; //instead of $omni_value[1];
```

Hope this helps